# How to get .xhtml code assist for IceFaces 4?

Tags: eclipse, jsf, icefaces

I am creating one project with **JSF+ICEFACES** integration, but in Eclipse I am not getting .xhtml code assist for IceFaces but it is giving code assist for jsf. I am sure that it is happening because of jars here is my complete maven dependency

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.icefaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>icefaces</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.icefaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>icefaces-ace</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.icepush/icepush -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.icepush</groupId>
        <artifactId>icepush</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

As I am using eclipse mars my jars are pointing to web-inf/lib.

[image]

And in xhtml I am adding these name spaces

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
xmlns:ice="http://www.icesoft.com/icefaces/component"
xmlns:ace="http://www.icefaces.org/icefaces/components">


</html>
```

[image]

Comment: If you application by itself works, there is no .jar missing.

Comment: But why it is not giving me auto suggestion ?

Comment: No idea.. I'm not an icefaces user.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the answer, as I think the problem with the dependency

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.icefaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>icefaces</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.icefaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>icefaces-ace</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: So only if you add the javaee-web-api dependency, the IceFaces completion starts working? Weird

Comment: Yah its true because before to that even if icefaces-ace dependency was added to maven I am unable to see that jar added so it did not provide me auto suggestion, but after adding  javaee-web-api  I was able to see icefaces-ace jar. its Weird  :)

Comment: No, it is not weird... it means an update failed... You could have added another jar most likely. And if the javaee-web-api is not there, most likely you have lots of compile errors...